# Can I have a GitHub hosted Github Enterprise instance running under my own domain?

Tags: github

I'm trying to figure out whether the following is possible, but I might be trying the wrong search queries or I'm not understanding some concepts around GitHub Enterprise, because so far I came up with no clear answer.

So

- I'd like to have a GitHub Enterprise instance running under my own domain (reachable like so: github.mydomain.com)
- But I'd like to have GitHub manage the instance for me (upgrades, backups, etc., i.e. a GitHub Enterprise Cloud instance)

What I found so far is that I could run my own instance on my own servers (or on an AWS EC2 instance) with a GitHub Enterprise Server instance, but I think that would mean that I'd be responsible for all the maintenance related to running that instance. The other option (GitHub Enterprise Cloud) seems to be to have my organization be hosted on the main GitHub portal (like github.com/myorg), and I'd like to have more, clearer separation than that.

Does anyone know whether I missed something obvious, or is what I'm trying to do not supported?

Comment: If you own the domain, can't you create a CNAME?

Comment: What I want is a complete separation from github.com - i.e. my repos showing up only under github.mydomain.com and not on github.com. While at the same time I'd like github to maintain my cloud server for me.

Also a CNAME record won't work, as it would need to point to a path on the server (like github.com/myorg) and not just to github itself.

Comment: You have conflicting requirements, unfortunately.

Comment: How are they conflicting requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to separate from GitHub.com, ask GH Team for a GitHub Enterprise Managed Users trial. It is hosted on GH.com but as a "separate instance," so like with GH Server, all users will be forced to have separate accounts with read-only access to public projects (outside of Your organization).
Main pros:

- separation from public GH.com
- no maintenance is needed from Your side
- no public projects/repositories/organizations available to create

**https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/admin/identity-and-access-management/using-enterprise-managed-users-for-iam/about-enterprise-managed-users**